# Djangoを使った投票アプリケーションの作成

Tags: python, django

Djangoを用いて, 投票アプリを作成しようと思っています.

設計としては
ページ1: トップページ. 質問作成者が新しい質問（セッション?）を作成する
ページ2: 質問作成者が選択肢などを設定し, 他ユーザの投票ページへのリンクを表示する
ページ3: 質問作成者以外のユーザーの投票画面
というものを考えています.

公式サイトにも（http://docs.djangoproject.jp/en/latest/intro/tutorial01.html）投票アプリの作成方法が載っていますが, webサイトの管理者のみが質問を作成できる形式で, webサイトを訪れた人が誰でも質問を作成できるものではないようです.

このような機能を実現するアプリの作り方が掲載されているwebサイト, ないし書籍などをご存知でしたら, 教えて下さい.

Comment: 本質的に同等の機能が実現できれば, 「投票アプリケーション」で無くても大丈夫です

Answer (score 1, accepted):

投票アプリを作りたいのであれば、Djangoのチュートリアルを参考にするのが良いです。

質問作成の部分だけ別途自分で考えて作り直す必要がありますが、凝った事をしなければチュートリアルの知識だけで対応できます。

質問に書いてあるリンク先は古いドキュメントなので、参考までに最新の日本語ドキュメントのリンクです。

[Django ドキュメント](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/)

他には、投票アプリではないですがDjangoでアプリケーションを作る手順を一通り説明しているものでは、以下が参考になると思います。

[Webアプリ開発実践：Djangoでシフト作成ページを作ろう！（はじめに） - Qiita](http://qiita.com/juniskw/items/530a94dce4fed5d4277f)